# excel vba msoShapeType enumeration item - msoIgxGraphic - 'not defined'

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

The following sub, which enumerates interesting properties of the shapes collection of the active worksheet, does not compile when `Case msoIgxGraphic` is included.  *Though I swear that it did compile earlier today.*  I'm using Excel 2007.  The [msoShapeType Enumeration defined for Office 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa432678%28v=office.12%29.aspx) clearly includes the value.

I've checked and checked again for a spelling error - can't find one.

I've added just the one sub to a module in a newly created, otherwise empty, workbook.  Still won't compile.  The error message is:

```
'Compile Error: Variable not Defined'
```

and `msoIgxGraphic` is highlighted.  Comment that stanza out of the select statement and it compiles and runs, no problem.  What am I missing?

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub GetShapeProperties()

        Dim sShapes As Shape, lLoop As Long
        Dim wsStart As Worksheet, WsNew As Worksheet
        Dim obj As OLEObject
        Dim obType As String

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ''''''''''LIST PROPERTIES OF SHAPES'''''''''''''
        ''''''''''Dave Hawley www.ozgrid.com''''''''''''
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Set wsStart = ActiveSheet
        Set WsNew = Sheets.Add

        If Len("Shapes Info") <> 0 Then
           Application.DisplayAlerts = False
           On Error Resume Next
           Worksheets("Shapes Info").Delete
           On Error GoTo 0
           Application.DisplayAlerts = True
           WsNew.Name = "Shapes Info"
        End If

        'Add headings for our lists. Expand as needed

        WsNew.Range("A1:X1") = _
         Array("Shape Name", ".OLEFormat.Object.Name", "Height", "Width", "Left", "Top" _
    , "AlternativeText" _
    , "Id" _
    , "Type" _
    , "Shape Type" _
    , "OLEFormat.Object.index" _
    , "OLEFormat.Object.Left" _
    , "OLEFormat.Object.Width" _
    , "OLEFormat.Object.Top" _
    , "OLEFormat.Object.Height" _
    , "OLEFormat.Object.TopLeftCell.Address" _
    , "OLEFormat.Object.BottomRightCell.Address" _
    , "OLEFormat.Object.ZOrder" _
    , "OLEFormat.Object.Locked" _
    , "OLEFormat.Object.Visible" _
    , "OnAction" _
    , "VerticalFlip" _
    , "ZOrderPosition")

        'Loop through all shapes on active sheet

        For Each sShapes In wsStart.Shapes

      'Increment Variable lLoop for row numbers

      lLoop = lLoop + 1

      With sShapes

          'Add shape properties

          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 1) = .Name
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 2) = .OLEFormat.Object.Name
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 3) = .Height
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 4) = .Width
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 5) = .Left
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 6) = .Top
          'Follow the same pattern for more
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 7) = .AlternativeText
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 8) = .ID
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 9) = .Type
          Select Case .Type
           Case msoAutoShape
            obType = "AutoShape"
           Case msoCallout
            obType = "Callout"
           Case msoCanvas
            obType = "Canvas"
           Case msoChart
            obType = "Chart"
           Case msoComment
            obType = "Comment"
           Case msoDiagram
            obType = "Diagram"
           Case msoEmbeddedOLEObject
            obType = "EmbeddedOLEObject"
           Case msoFormControl
             Select Case .FormsControlType
                Case xlButtonControl
                    obType = "FormsControlType Button"
                Case xlCheckBox
                    obType = "FormsControlType CheckBox"
                Case xlDropDown
                    obType = "FormsControlType DropDown"
                Case xlEditBox
                    obType = "FormsControlType EditBox"
                Case xlGroupBox
                    obType = "FormsControlType GroupBox"
                Case xlLabel
                    obType = "FormsControlType Label"
                Case xlListBox
                    obType = "FormsControlType ListBox"
                Case xlOptionButton
                    obType = "FormsControlType OptionButton"
                Case xlScrollBar
                    obType = "FormsControlType ScrollBar"
                Case xlSpinner
                    obType = "FormsControlType Spinner"
                Case Else
                    obType = "Unknown MsoFormsControlType"
              End Select
           Case msoFreeform
            obType = "Freeform"
           Case msoGroup
            obType = "Group"
           Case msoIgxGraphic
            obType = "IgxGraphic"
           Case msoInk
            obType = "Ink"
           Case msoInkComment
            obType = "InkComment"
           Case msoLine
            obType = "Line"
           Case msoLinkedOLEObject
            obType = "LinkedOLEObject"
           Case msoLinkedPicture
            obType = "LinkedPicture"
           Case msoMedia
            obType = "Media"
           Case msoOLEControlObject
            Set obj = .OLEFormat.Object
            obType = "OLEControlObject " + "(" + obj.Application.Name + "): " + TypeName(obj.Object)
           Case msoPicture
            obType = "Picture"
           Case msoPlaceholder
            obType = "Placeholder"
           Case msoScriptAnchor
            obType = "ScriptAnchor"
           Case msoShapeTypeMixed
            obType = "ShapeTypeMixed"
           Case msoTable
            obType = "Table"
           Case msoTextBox
            obType = "TextBox"
           Case msoTextEffect
            obType = "TextEffect"
           Case Else
            obType = "Unknown MsoShapeType"
        End Select
        WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 10) = obType

        WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 12) = .OLEFormat.Object.Index
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 13) = .OLEFormat.Object.Left
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 14) = .OLEFormat.Object.Width
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 15) = .OLEFormat.Object.Top
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 16) = .OLEFormat.Object.Height
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 17) = .OLEFormat.Object.TopLeftCell.Address
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 18) = .OLEFormat.Object.BottomRightCell.Address
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 19) = .OLEFormat.Object.ZOrder
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 20) = .OLEFormat.Object.Locked
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 21) = .OLEFormat.Object.Visible
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 22) = .OnAction
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 24) = .VerticalFlip
          WsNew.Cells(lLoop + 1, 25) = .ZOrderPosition

      End With

      Next sShapes
      WsNew.Columns.AutoFit

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I use the object browser to look at the `MsoShapeType` enum, it looks like `msoIgxGraphic` was replaced with `msoSmartArt`.

My best guess is this change happened as part of a Windows\Office update. Do you know if any updates were applied between when it was working and when it failed?

Comment: Well, I guess I have MS to thank for a lovely breaking change. I never imagined they'd remove an existing member of a published enum definition.